# using System.Deployment doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, version-control, blazor, libraries

I've tried looking for `System.Deployment` to use this code in my Blazor Server application:
[image]

But System.Deployment is not in my project system, nor in the available Project References, I looked on Google to find a downloadable .dll link and Microsoft doesn't seem to have it. What am I missing? I've tried `using System.Deployment` and `using System.Deployment.Application`, neither works.

[image: My project references, available libraries]

Comment: If I try to change the framework version to .NET Core/.NET 5+ on the documentation, it says the class isn't available. It looks to be a .NET Framework-only thing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0

Comment: System.Deployment is part of .NET _Framework_, so is not available for use with .NET _Core_ for Blazor applications.

Comment: I see, so is there an alternative way of getting the assembly version to use in my code?

Comment: Does this answer your question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36351866/getting-the-version-of-my-c-sharp-app

Answer (score 7):

Just reference the "[FrameworkExtract.System.Deployment](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FrameworkExtract.System.Deployment)" nuget to your project.

Have a nice day,

Comment: thanks, this saved me 30 minutes of searching time.

Comment: in case anyone runs into this again, I'm using .net 7.0 and reference this dll won't work and gave an error message saying can't load this dll. Instead adding this packge, I used the solution from this link. it has a couple solutions for the newer .net verion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71718870/displaying-clickonce-version-number-of-net-6-wpf-application

Answer (score 0):

If you're not looking to rely on an external package, you can rely on the registry to keep track of your applications version in it's uninstall.

Basically when you go to Add/Remove and check a version.

```
RegistryKey? registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\");

if (registryKey != null) return;

var programKeys = registryKey.GetSubKeyNames();

foreach (var keyName in programKeys)
{
    RegistryKey? programKey = registryKey.OpenSubKey(keyName);

    object? displayName = programKey?.GetValue("DisplayName");
    object? version = programKey?.GetValue("DisplayVersion");

    if (displayName != null && $"{displayName}" == <YourApplicationName>)
        VersionText.Text = $"Version: {version}";
        
    programKey?.Close();
}

registryKey.Close();
```

I'd use the above answer and just install the missing functionality through a nuget package but I thought I'd leave this solution here for anyone who wants a little more control over how they're getting the version info.